# Unable to access External IP from Docker Container created using Docker Desktop in a Windows VM

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, docker-desktop

I have installed Docker Desktop for windows within a VSphere VM. I have created a docker container from which I'm trying to access an external IP, needed for container start up. Connectivity is not getting established. I am able to connect to the external IP from my VM without any issues. What settings in DOcker Desktop/ changes am i missing?

Please help as I'm unable to get to a solution.

Thanks

I have tried setting up a proxy and also changing the Docker Desktop settings for Default address. Nothing is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried installing Docker desktop for Windows using WSL instead of Hyper-V. The network issues are no more observed. Please check below steps:

1. install wsl using wsl --install from powershell in Windows VM.
2. Then install Docker desktop for Windows with checkedbox checked for WSL.